# Finding the area of two shapes

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

A circle of radius $5$cm and a square of sides $8$cm have the same centre. Find the total area of the region that belongs to either the square or the circle, but not both.

[image: Diagram for the question]

I have constructed a diagram using Geogebra and I believe that I am required to find the shaded green region and the shaded pink region. My approach is to find the sum of the area $T = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H$. Then subtract $T$ from the area of the square to find the pink shaded region and also subtract $T$ from the area of circle to get the green shaded region.

But I have trouble finding the area for $B, D, F, H$ because I don't have the angle of each sector to find the area.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: By symmetry, just look the {x>0, y>0} region. The area of each triangle is 6 following Pythagoras' theorem. The radius of the circle is the hypothenuse. The green area is just the difference between the circle sector and the triangle.

Comment: @FormerMath if I can find the angle closest to the center of each triangle in the {x>0, y>0} region, I can minus it from 90 degrees to find the angle of the sector! Hence finding the area of each sector! Am I onto something here?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @FormerMath in hindsight, How can anyone draw this diagram with this much precision without the help of some sort of graphing software?